# PostgreSQL - Recursively getting time ranges by intersecting two tables

Tags: postgresql

Given the following table structure:

#### Working hours

| id | day_of_week | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 8:30:00 | 18:30:00 |

#### Bookings

| id | date | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-02-21 | 10:30:00 | 12:30:00 |
| 2 | 2023-02-21 | 13:30:00 | 14:30:00 |

I'm looking for a query to get all the available (non-booked) time ranges.

#### Expected output

| date | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-02-21 | 8:30:00 | 10:30:00 |
| 2023-02-21 | 12:30:00 | 13:30:00 |
| 2023-02-21 | 14:30:00 | 18:30:00 |

But I can't quite grasp how to do that in a single query.

Running PostgreSQL 15.1

Comment: Add version of Postgres to your question.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to [Better Range Types in Postgres 14: Turning 100 Lines of SQL Into 3](https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/better-range-types-in-postgres-14-turning-100-lines-of-sql-into-3). Changed
`day_of_week` to 2 as that is what `dow` or `isodow` will return for `2023-02-21`.

```
create table bookings (id integer, date_fld date, start_time time, end_time time);

insert into bookings VALUES (1, '2023-02-21', '10:30:00', '12:30:00');
insert into bookings VALUES (2, '2023-02-21', '13:30:00', '14:30:00');

create table working_hours (id integer,  day_of_week integer, start_time time, end_time time);

insert into working_hours values (1, 2, '8:30:00', '18:30:00');


SELECT
    lower(t)::date AS date,
    lower(t)::time AS start_time,
    upper(t)::time AS end_time
FROM (
    SELECT
        unnest(tsmultirange (tsrange(date_fld + wh.start_time, date_fld + wh.end_time)) - range_agg (tsrange(date_fld + bk.start_time, date_fld + bk.end_time))) AS t
    FROM
        bookings AS bk
        JOIN working_hours AS wh ON day_of_week = extract(dow FROM date_fld)
    GROUP BY
        date_fld, wh.start_time, wh.end_time) AS times;
                                                        


 date    | start_time | end_time 
------------+------------+----------
 02/21/2023 | 08:30:00   | 10:30:00
 02/21/2023 | 12:30:00   | 13:30:00
 02/21/2023 | 14:30:00   | 18:30:00
```